# Exit status wrong with local variable assignment

Tags: bash

The example below shows how if `temp_file` is made `local` as part of the same line that `mktemp` is called then the exit status retrieved using `$?` is always zero, regardless of whether the command succeeded or failed (`mktemp_xyz` is used so that it always fails). If `temp_file` is made `local` in advance then the `$?` exit status is as expected.

Can someone explain what is going on here please?

```
#!/bin/bash

test_1()
{
    local temp_file=$(mktemp_xyz -q -t "test.tmp.XXXXXX")
    local make_temp_file_ret_val=$?

    echo "temp_file: $temp_file"
    echo "make_temp_file_ret_val: $make_temp_file_ret_val"
}

test_2()
{
    local temp_file=""
    temp_file=$(mktemp_xyz -q -t "test.tmp.XXXXXX")
    local make_temp_file_ret_val=$?

    echo "temp_file: $temp_file"
    echo "make_temp_file_ret_val: $make_temp_file_ret_val"
}

test_1
echo ""
test_2
```

Output is:

```
$ ./test 
./test: line 6: mktemp_xyz: command not found
temp_file: 
make_temp_file_ret_val: 0

./test: line 16: mktemp_xyz: command not found
temp_file: 
make_temp_file_ret_val: 127
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`local` is a command itself, not just a modifier to an assignment statement. In `test1`, you are recording the exit status of the `local` command, not the command in the command substitution. In `test2`, you've separated the `local` command from the assignment to the variable marked as local, so `$?` contains the exit status you are expecting.

---

Unrelated, but you don't need to initialize a variable when marking it as local. This works just fine:

```
local temp_file
temp_file=$(mktemp_xyz -q -t "test.tmp.XXXXXX")
```

`temp_file` remains unset until you actually assign a value to it, but the *name* is local once you actually do assign a value.

Comment: This is shellcheck [SC2155](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2155). The wiki uses `export` but the same applies here.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it.