# Setting a shell variable from stdout *or* fallback if command fails

Tags: bash, sh

My script calls an external command (e.g. `readlink`) which will either:

- write a useful string to its stdout on success, or…
- return a non-zero exit status on failure

I know how to do each individually, e.g. to capture the stdout I can use

```
MY_VAR=$(readlink /)
```

Or to check the result I could use:

```
if readlink /tmp; then
   echo "Success"
fi
```

But is there a clean/clear way to do both ± simultaneously? I'm not sure the following would work:

```
if MY_VAL=`readlink "$MY_ARG"`; then
    echo "Value is ${MY_VAL}"
else
    echo "Not found"
fi
```

**UPDATE**: so I tried that, and it *did* work. But is it only a coincidence, e.g. happens to work because readlink's output is empty at the same time it errors?

As a particular constraint, I need to do this in an environment where `set -e` is specified, i.e. if other commands return an error the overall script will fail. Generic shell preferred, unless bash has a better mechanism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just:

```
if MY_VAR=$(readlink /); then
   echo "Success"
fi
```

Command substitution return status is the return status of the last command executed (or the return status of the subshell executed inside). So `$(true; false;)` returns nonzero status. The return status of a line with command substitution is equal to the last executed command. So:

```
 a=$(true)$(false)
```

will always return nonzero return status. But:

```
 a=$(false)$(true)
```

will return a zero return status, because the last executed command substitution command is `true` which returns a zero status.

It's normal in scripts to do `if var=$(...); then` which allows for checking the return status of a command while saving it's standard output.

Don't use backticks `. They are the same as `$( .. )` but are less readable, can't be nested and are [deprecated](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete).

Comment: Very helpful, thanks for expanding on your original confirmation! Appreciate the style feedback on the backticks too.

Comment: Caveat: if you use something like `if local var=$(somecommand)`, then you're testing the status of the `local` command, not of `somecommand`. The same goes for `export`, `declare`, etc. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33372559/exit-status-wrong-with-local-variable-assignment).

Answer (score 0):

You can check the exit status of your last command executed with $?  In shell and see if it holds 0 for success or 1 for failure

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work if `set -e` is active, since a failed command execution will cause my own script to automatically fail before I am able to check the `$?` myself.

Comment: @natevw Don't use `set -e`; there are a *lot* of corner cases where it won't work like you expect. It's better to do your own error handling.

Answer (score 0):

So my "wish it worked like this example" **is** correct!

```
if MY_VAL=$(readlink "$MY_ARG"); then
    echo "Value is ${MY_VAL}"
else
    echo "Not found"
fi
```

The reason is that the "exit code" of a variable assignment like this [is the exit code of the command inside](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20157997/179583). The variable assignment happens *and* the exit status is propagated, on both success and failure.